# Pygame: rotating images subsurface

Tags: rotation, pygame

I have been trying to rotate sprites in pygame for quite a while. I came across this to help me rotate it around the center:

http://www.pygame.org/wiki/RotateCenter

But I don't really understand what the `rot_image = rot_image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()` line does. There are a lot of pages about this kind of thing but they haven't helped me. I tried it without that line and it spins oddly. Could anyone tell me how that line prevents that?

Answer (score 0):

From [pygame.transform.rotate](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate):

> Unless rotating by 90 degree increments, the image will be padded
>   larger to hold the new size.

So, the quoted line, wich `*only* works with square images`, keeps the original dimensions using the original center. Keep in mind the with this method the rotated image could be "trimmed" (ie: loose some area) in the attempt to keep it's size.

Comment: sorry i dont really understand.    how does this line keep origional dimensions and center? i would like to go into more detail on how i dont understand but I just dont get it.

Comment: hmm if anyone knows of a good place to explain subsurfaces because maybe my little understaning of them is wrong. it doesnt say much on the pygame website

Comment: Because rot_rect has the original dimensions of the image (before rotating). A subsurface is just a *pointer* to an specific area of the original surface (image), when you copy it you get a copy of that area in a new surface. So you are grabbing a rectangle of the original dimensions from the rotated image.